# How do I know if a bread is whole grain (without the label)?

Tags: food

I wonder whether it is possible to know if a bread is whole grain, without looking the label (since sometimes I don't have it, e.g., restaurant).

Color can give a hint:

[image]

but is not always reliable.

Comment: I bake a lot and I wouldn't dare to declare something "whole grain" except for a few select types like [pumpernickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpernickel). Everything looking more "generic bread-ish" is basically impossible to classify on taste or texture alone.

Comment: If you can't tell, what does it matter?

Comment: @JDługosz I prefer whole grain.

Comment: But you said you can't distinguish it! "How do I know if this is more flavorful and delicious?" Is a self-answering question if it's meaningful at all.

Comment: @JDługosz I prefer whole grain from a nutritional standpoint. I cannot make a difference by taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can always ask the person selling the bread. It is best to look at the label as the colors can be misleading.

Comment: I agree; I can make bread that looks like whole grain but doesn't meet the FDA definitions (or, most likely, those of other countries).  If the bread has no label, the seller can effectively tell you anything, so there's no way to be sure.  Even pumpernickel can have 50% white flour, and color (especially for dark rye breads) is often added by adding coffee.

Comment: Sure, label or vendor is a good source, but what if I don't have access to it?

Answer (score -1):

In this case that bread is not whole grain, in general whole grain bread is darker. Also whole grain bread is not as soft as white bread.

Comment: While generally true, that is not the case for specialty flours which can be bleached and extremely finely ground.